# Cloudfront access denied with OAI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to serve react application from s3. For security i locked its access to CloudFront OAI. I followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) along with [OAI settings](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/).

But unfortunately it gave me 403 forbidden error.
Then i added default root object `index.html` which made it work but i when i tried to access any other page like login, it again gave me access denied.

Subsequently i added 403 custom error page with response page as /index.html it worked.

SO my question is why do i need to add default root object or 403 error page to make it work? is this how cloudfront works?

Update :- even if i don't set default root object, and set custom 403 error response this works.

Comment: Root object is needed, but I'm not sure what do you meany by 403 errors. If you redirect 403 to index.html, how do you access other files on your page?

Comment: I am using auth0 login, whenver i try clicking on login without 403 custom error set on cloudfront it shows acccess denied, but when its set it allows to redirect to auth0 login page